# pythonのPandasデータフレームから、所定の辞書型に変換する方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, pandas

pythonのPandasデータフレームで、以下のようなデータがあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これを、以下のように変換する方法を知りたいです。

```
x={'item1':1,'item2':1,'item4':1}
y={'item1':1,'item3':1}
```

ちなみに、これで実行すれば「0」の値も含まれてしまい、惜しいわけです。

```
In:dict(df.ix['x'])
Out:{'item1': 1, 'item2': 1, 'item3': 0, 'item4': 1}
```

説明が不足していれば補足しますので、回答いただければありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`ix()` メソッドでフィルタリングします。

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
      [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]
    ], index=['x', 'y'], columns=['item1','item2','item3', 'item4'])
>>> df
   item1  item2  item3  item4
x      1      1      0      1
y      1      0      1      0

>>> dict(df.ix['x',(df.ix['x'] == 1)])
{'item2': 1, 'item1': 1, 'item4': 1}
>>> dict(df.ix['y',(df.ix['y'] == 1)])
{'item3': 1, 'item1': 1}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
確かに、これでできますね。ドはまりしてほかの視点がなくなってしまっていました。発想の転換というか、アプローチ法をいくつかもつのは大事なことですね。
助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

一行で書くならこんな感じですかね

`x, y = [col[col != 0].to_dict() for col in [df.loc[row] for row in df.index]]`

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こういう方法もあるのですね、なるほど勉強になりました。
dict()に慣れてしまっていて、to_dict()という考えがでませんでした。。